# Calling stored procedures from PHP, with a PHP variable as the IN parameter

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have tables that look like this:

[image: Category Table]
[image: Sub Category Table]

I have a procedure that I am trying to use to get all the SubCategoryNames that have the same CategoryID as a given CategoryName: this one:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getSubCategory(IN category TEXT) READS SQL DATA
     BEGIN
         SELECT `SubCategoryName` FROM `sub_category` WHERE `CategoryID` = (SELECT `CategoryID` FROM `category` WHERE `CategoryName` = category);
     END
```

For some reason, when I try to call this procedure from the PHP code, with a PHP variable, like so:

```
$result = $connection->query($connection->real_escape_string("CALL `jcarillo_db`.getSubCategories(" . $superCategory . ")"));
    // based on that, print the appropriate menu
    if ($result)
    {
        // print an <option> for each row in the result set (remember, $result will have one entry per row!)
        while ($row = $result->fetch_row())
        {
            require_once("argumentParser.php");
            printf('<option name="%sOption" value="%s">%s</option>\n', toCamelCase($row[0]), $row[0], $row[0]);
        }
        // don't forget to free result set!
        $result->close();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Fetch failed(" . $connection->errno . ")" . $connection->error;
    }
```

The "Fetch failed" gets echoed, instead of the results! Yet, for some reason, when I try to call that very same stored procedure from the database (namely, through phpMyAdmin), it works! What the heck am I doing wrong?!?! `$connection` is set up correctly, and I know this because my attempt to echo the CategoryNames from the category table works with it!

Comment: If I specify an OUT parameter, it will complain of multiple results!

Comment: Just guessing here, but does `$superCategory` perhaps need to be quoted?

Comment: You mean by adding `\"` between the parentheses?

Comment: I do that, and it says that I have an error in my syntax, at that exact spot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to call the function with a String parameter and you are passing it without letting the MySQL knowing its a string.

Try this instead:

```
$result = $connection->query("CALL `jcarillo_db`.getSubCategories('".$connection->real_escape_string($superCategory)."')");
```

Comment: Somehow, it is complaining of an error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'Meat\')'` when `$superCategory == "Meat"`

Comment: try removing the `real_escape_string` function it might cause this problem. just to validate and to see if that's the problem. if it solve that problem you should move the `real_escape_string` to wrap only the variables. and it should work. (I've edited my answer)